# Function returns base class instead of derived class, is this a coding mistake or a Visual C++ bug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, inheritance, iterator, visual-studio-2015

Given the following code, GCC handles fine. Visual C++ 2010-2015, however, gives the following error message indicating that it's treating the iterator member of reverse_iterator as it's base type, not it's derived type:

"Error  1   error C2039: 'get' : is not a member of 'std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag,element_type,ptrdiff_t,element_type *,element_type &>'"

Obviously the code is a cut-down example to illustrate the situation and does not relate to the original context, which we will not be addressing here. The only question to be answered is the one in the title.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>


template <class element_type> class container
{
public:
    class iterator : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, element_type, std::ptrdiff_t, element_type *, element_type &>
    {
    private:
        element_type *a;

    public:
        element_type * get()
        {
            return a;
        }

        void set(element_type *value)
        {
            a = value;
        }
    };



    class reverse_iterator : public std::reverse_iterator<iterator>
    {
    private:
        iterator der1;

    public:
        iterator base()
        {
            return iterator(der1);
        }
    };

};




int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    container<int>::iterator c;
    container<int>::reverse_iterator d;

    cout << c.get() << " ";
    cout << d.base().get() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously if you compile this you'll find "c.get()" functions perfectly, d.base().get() provides the error message.

This is a constructed example specifically to illustrate the issue. Please do Not provide answers that do not relate to the issue.

Please note that this error does not result when another artificially-constructed base class is used - it is specific to std::iterator under visual studio.

NOTE: Thanks to 1201ProgramAlarm for answering the question. The solution is to clarify the namespace of the iterator instance within reverse_iterator, so that container::iterator is the one used. To do that you simply use "typename container::iterator" instead of "iterator" within the reverse_iterator declaration.

Comment: Also you don't want to hear it: Inheriting from std::reverse_iterator is wrong in the beginning. It is not a base-class. In general, most classes in the STL are not meant to be used as base-classes. This is easy to see because most of them do not have a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reverse_iterator` is derived from `std::iterator` (it's in `<xutility>`) so your references to `iterator` in your `reverse_iterator` class will refer to the std version, not the one in your class.

Comment: This inheritance relationship's required until C++17 (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator)), which could explain a recent GCC version not exhibiting the issue if set to use its latest features.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I found that using typename container::iterator was enough to correctly specify the right namespace within reverse_iterator. Do you mind if I update your answer to include that? Otherwise will put post-note in the question.

Comment: Probably a post note in the question would be clearest.

Answer (score 0):

Do not inherit from `std::reverse_iterator`.

```
#include <iterator>


template <class element_type> class container
{
public:
    class iterator : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, element_type, std::ptrdiff_t, element_type *, element_type &>
    {
    private:
        element_type *a;

    public:
        element_type get()
        {
            return *a;
        }

        void set(element_type *value)
        {
            *a = value;
        }
    };

    using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;

    iterator begin();

    reverse_iterator rbegin() {
         return std::make_reverse_iterator( end() );
    }
};
```

Comment: Although an elegant solution if only using pointer-based ie. simple iterators, this gets complicated if implementing anything other than a simple iterator - as multiple functions will need to be overridden from iterator, for reverse_iterator (ie. not simple pass-through functions).

Comment: @metamorphosis I don't understand your comment. The iterator is taken from the source code in the question. For std::reverse_iterator, the implementation does not matter as long as it is a bidirectional iterator. So whenever you implement a standard-conformant bidirectional iterator, you get the reverse_iterator almost for free. Of course, a custom one may be more efficient.

Comment: As I said, that may not work for a more complex iterator. For example. In the case of a bounded iterator you want to bound at [0] (begin), but for the reverse_iterator you want to bound at [-1] (rend). 
In more extreme cases, reversing through a structure may require a very different algorithm for going forwards through it.
You've said "don't inherit from std::reverse_iterator", but your solution doesn't actually answer the question. Once the question is answered, inheriting from std::reverse_iterator is fine.

Comment: @metamorphosis I still don't see the point. If you have a bidirectional iterator, however it is implemented, std::reverse_iterator works. If you have some other iterator, it won't. If your bounded iterator fullfils the requirements for a bidirectional iterator then it has to work. Otherwise, it cannot be a bidirectional iterator.

Comment: @metamorphosis Inheriting from std::reverse_iterator is never fine. It does not have a virtual destructor, so it will likely result in undefined behavior. And it does not have any virtual functions, so there is no point in inheriting from it. And yes, I did not answer the question but wanted to show a general problem in the posted code.

Comment: Okay, I'm not engaging with this any more